# Standalone MaterialViewPager sample app

Tags: android, android-studio

I recently found the MaterialViewPager library [on Github](https://github.com/florent37/MaterialViewPager) where the author also included a sample app. The sample app on Github is dependent to two other moduels :

- materialviewpager
- materialviewpagercontroller

I tried to convert the sample app provided into an standalone app by creating a blank project in Android Studio and including :

```
compile ('com.github.florent37:materialviewpager:1.2.0@aar'){
    transitive = true
}
```

in the build file. Then I copied all the files in the sample folder to the app but I got so many errors in every file, after removing a lot of files and getting the app to compile I got this:

[image]

Since I am new to Android Studio and I spent two hours trying this without any success, can someone please let me know how I can convert the sample app the author provided to a standalone sample app?

Comment: Can you show us where exactly you put this in your gradle.build file and exactly what the rest of your gradle.build file looks like?